# Need to take only one entry pertaining to particular name as in first column and iterate over the file

Tags: shell, awk

I have a file called Files1 which  has below data, where i Need to take only the line (entire line) which has all the column entries (ie $1...to ..$12) and iterate over the file..
example: for name "testvnc02"  it should only print below line as it has all the fields of its name and ignore rest of the line and take another name and do the same.

> testvnc02 out: anders   pts/83       192.168.87.1      Mon Feb 20
>   00:31 - 01:04  00:33

```
[testvnc02 ] out:
[testvnc02 ] out:
[testvnc02 ] out:
testvnc02 out:
testvnc02 out: anders   pts/83       192.168.87.1      Mon Feb 20 00:31 - 01:04  00:33
testvnc02 out: curtist  pts/1927      192.202.45.84     Thu Feb  9 17:54 - 19:55  02:00
testvnc02 out: curtist  pts/1928      :32.0            Thu Feb  9 17:56   still logged in
testvnc02 out: echolu   pts/82       :13              Tue Feb 14 01:07   still logged in
testvnc02 out: echolu   pts/83       :13.0            Tue Feb 14 01:08 - 01:23 3+00:14
testvnc02 out: garimas  pts/71       test-garimas.caden Fri Feb 17 02:22 - 03:23  01:01
testvnc02 out: garimas  pts/71       test-garimas.caden Sun Feb 12 22:54 - 00:04  01:09
testvnc02 out: garimas  pts/83       test-garimas.caden Mon Feb 20 01:39 - 02:39  01:00
testvnc02 out: garimas  pts/84       test-garimas.caden Tue Feb 14 04:46 - 05:48  01:01
testvnc02 out: hjyu     pts/87       testvnc02:28.0     Wed Feb  8 16:30   still logged in
testvnc02 out: hongshaw pts/17       192.168.222.27    Tue Feb  7 21:39 - 03:52  06:13
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/4        :4.0             Fri Feb 192 00:55 - 07:30 2+06:35
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/4        :4.0             Sun Feb 12 07:30 - 22:54 3+15:24
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/4        :4.0             Tue Feb  7 21:36 - 00:55 2+03:18
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/71       :4.0             Fri Feb 192 02:49 - 03:36  00:47
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/71       :4.0             Mon Feb 13 09:58 - 22:54 2+12:55
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/71       :4.0             Sun Feb 12 07:21 - 07:25  00:03
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/71       :4.0             Tue Feb  7 22:20 - 01:30 2+03:192
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/81       :4.0             Fri Feb 192 03:24 - 03:36  00:12
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/81       :4.0             Mon Feb 13 192:02 - 22:53 2+12:51
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/81       :4.0             Tue Feb  7 22:21 - 01:30 2+03:09
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/84       :4.0             Fri Feb 192 03:32 - 03:36  00:03
testvnc02 out: npitla   pts/84       :4.0             Wed Feb  8 09:24 - 00:54 1+15:30
testvnc02 out: pedro    pts/89       testvcut07.perence Wed Feb 15 01:41 - 01:50  00:09
testvnc02 out: pedro    pts/89       testvcut07.perence Wed Feb 15 01:52 - 01:55  00:02
testvnc02 out: ruizh    pts/89       szlnx4.perence.c Wed Feb 15 21:09 - 21:55 3+00:46
testvnc02 out: sbrahma  pts/71       test-sbrahma.caden Fri Feb 17 14:46 - 14:53  00:06
testvnc02 out: sonamt   pts/85       test-sonamt.caden Wed Feb  8 22:21 - 23:41  01:19
testvnc02 out: sungsikh pts/1927      :29.0            Thu Feb  9 16:13 - 16:19  00:06
testvnc02 out: sungsikh pts/4        :29.0            Thu Feb 16 12:55   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/1920      :31              Thu Feb  9 192:19   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/1921      :31              Thu Feb  9 192:19   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/1922      :31              Thu Feb  9 192:20   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/1923      :31              Thu Feb  9 192:20   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/1924      :31              Thu Feb  9 192:20   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/1925      :31              Thu Feb  9 192:21   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/85       192.168.12.43     Thu Feb  9 08:59 - 09:22  00:23
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/85       :31              Thu Feb  9 192:17   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/90       :31              Thu Feb  9 09:00   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/91       :31              Thu Feb  9 09:00   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/92       :31              Thu Feb  9 09:00   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/93       :31              Thu Feb  9 09:00   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/94       :31              Thu Feb  9 09:00   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/95       :31              Thu Feb  9 09:00   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/96       :31              Thu Feb  9 09:00   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/97       :31              Thu Feb  9 09:00   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/98       :31              Thu Feb  9 192:18   still logged in
testvnc02 out: tao1wang pts/99       :31              Thu Feb  9 192:18   still logged in
testvnc02 out: vsanjay  pts/71       :12              Sun Feb 19 23:06   still logged in
testvnc02 out: vsanjay  pts/81       :12              Sun Feb 19 23:06   still logged in
testvnc02 out: vsanjay  pts/88       :12              Wed Feb 15 01:30   still logged in
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/0        :14.0            Wed Feb  8 09:192 - 11:50  02:40
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/0        :14.0            Wed Feb  8 11:50 - 12:192  00:19
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/1926      :14.0            Thu Feb  9 11:04 - 17:38 5+06:33
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/17       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 09:11 - 09:12  00:01
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/58       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 09:13 - 11:49  02:36
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/71       :14.0            Fri Feb 192 12:50 - 12:52  00:01
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/71       :14.0            Fri Feb 192 13:25 - 13:27  00:02
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/84       :14.0            Tue Feb 14 17:38 - 19:11  01:33
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/84       :14.0            Tue Feb 14 19:18   still logged in
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/85       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 11:49 - 16:20  04:31
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/85       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 16:20 - 18:31  02:192
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/87       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 12:12 - 14:20  02:08
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/87       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 14:20 - 16:20  01:59
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/88       :14.0            Thu Feb  9 11:46 - 22:05  192:19
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/88       :14.0            Tue Feb 14 18:21 - 19:26  01:04
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/88       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 16:03 - 16:192  00:07
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/88       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 16:19 - 16:20  00:01
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/88       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 17:12 - 11:04  17:52
testvnc02 out: yulizhu  pts/89       :14.0            Wed Feb  8 18:27 - 17:38 5+23:11

[testvnc04] out:
[testvnc04] out:
testvnc04 out: amitv    pts/22       textnntv.cadenc Mon Feb 20 02:14 - 03:14  01:00
testvnc04 out: amitv    pts/27       textnntv.cadenc Sun Feb 12 20:55 - 21:56  01:00
testvnc04 out: amitv    pts/50       textnntv.cadenc Thu Feb 16 09:29 - 192:29  01:00
testvnc04 out: amitv    pts/50       textnntv.cadenc Tue Feb 14 21:55 - 22:55  01:00
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/22       192.16833.221.89    Sun Feb 19 21:42 - 22:53  01:192
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/23       :3.0             Sun Feb 19 21:43   still logged in
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/24       :3.0             Sun Feb 19 21:43   still logged in
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/25       :3.0             Sun Feb 19 21:43   still logged in
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/26       :3.0             Sun Feb 12 01:01 - 21:41 7+20:39
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/26       :3.0             Sun Feb 19 21:43   still logged in
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/56       192.16833.221.89    Sun Feb 19 21:40 - 21:41  00:01
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/56       :3.0             Sun Feb 19 21:43   still logged in
testvnc04 out: amyluo   pts/57       :3.0             Sun Feb 19 21:43   still logged in
testvnc04 out: dclor    pts/27       192.202.45.91     Sun Feb 12 16:42 - 17:43  01:00
testvnc04 out: dclor    pts/28       :4               Sun Feb 12 16:43   still logged in
testvnc04 out: dclor    pts/29       :4               Sun Feb 12 16:43   still logged in
testvnc04 out: dclor    pts/49       :4               Mon Feb 13 17:13   still logged in
testvnc04 out: dclor    pts/51       :4               Tue Feb 14 08:32   still logged in
testvnc04 out: dclor    pts/9        :4               Mon Feb 20 13:28   still logged in
testvnc04 out: horeftis pts/48       test-horeftis.cade Mon Feb 13 14:42 - 14:44  00:01
testvnc04 out: jinyi    pts/27       192.16833.2192.16828   Sun Feb 12 18:36 - 18:44  00:07
testvnc04 out: jinyi    pts/30       :5.0             Sun Feb 12 18:40   still logged in
testvnc04 out: joao     pts/22       test-joao.perence. Mon Feb 20 04:57   still logged in
testvnc04 out: joao     pts/9        :52.0            Tue Feb 14 04:29 - 06:15  01:45
testvnc04 out: joao     pts/9        :52.0            Tue Feb 14 06:15 - 02:01  19:46
testvnc04 out: joao     pts/9        :52.0            Wed Feb 15 02:01 - 04:58 5+02:56
testvnc04 out: jolinr   pts/50       testfib240.perence Tue Feb 14 17:54 - 18:05  00:192
testvnc04 out: jolinr   pts/52       :6.0             Tue Feb 14 17:56   still logged in
testvnc04 out: jolinr   pts/53       :6               Tue Feb 14 17:56   still logged in
testvnc04 out: jolinr   pts/56       :6               Thu Feb 16 18:08 - 18:44  00:36
testvnc04 out: jolinr   pts/57       :6               Thu Feb 16 18:11 - 18:44  00:33
testvnc04 out: jolinr   pts/58       :6               Thu Feb 16 18:20 - 18:44  00:23
testvnc04 out: jolinr   pts/59       :6               Thu Feb 16 18:22 - 18:44  00:22
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/22       vm1lnx3.perence. Mon Feb 20 00:27 - 00:42  00:15
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/56       vm1lnx3.perence. Fri Feb 17 01:52 - 04:08  02:16
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/56       vm1lnx3.perence. Fri Feb 17 08:57 - 09:27  00:29
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/56       vm1lnx3.perence. Fri Feb 17 192:19 - 11:41  01:21
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/56       vm1lnx3.perence. Fri Feb 17 21:59 - 23:00  01:00
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/56       vm1lnx3.perence. Sat Feb 18 01:36 - 01:45  00:09
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/56       vm1lnx3.perence. Sat Feb 18 06:41 - 11:17  04:36
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/56       vm1lnx3.perence. Sun Feb 19 18:53 - 19:56  01:03
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/56       vm1lnx3.perence. Thu Feb 16 21:37 - 00:15  02:38
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/57       vm1lnx3.perence. Fri Feb 17 09:04 - 09:27  00:22
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/57       vm1lnx3.perence. Sat Feb 18 06:44 - 192:18  03:33
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/58       vm1lnx3.perence. Mon Feb 20 02:25 - 18:38  16:12
testvnc04 out: jxie     pts/60       vm1lnx3.perence. Thu Feb 16 18:31 - 18:51  00:20
testvnc04 out: kitagawa pts/21       :48.0            Sun Feb 12 06:47   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kitagawa pts/27       :48.0            Mon Feb 13 01:12   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kitagawa pts/48       :48.0            Mon Feb 13 16:54   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kitagawa pts/50       cdtest135.perence. Wed Feb 15 01:48 - 02:48  01:00
testvnc04 out: kitagawa pts/54       :51.0            Thu Feb 16 15:32   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kitagawa pts/59       :48.0            Mon Feb 20 15:34   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/31       test-kmchow.cadenc Mon Feb 13 09:54   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/32       :99              Mon Feb 13 09:55   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/33       :99              Mon Feb 13 09:55   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/34       :99              Mon Feb 13 09:55   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/35       :99              Mon Feb 13 09:55   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/36       :99              Mon Feb 13 09:55   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/37       :99              Mon Feb 13 09:55   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/38       :99              Mon Feb 13 09:55   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/39       :99              Mon Feb 13 09:55   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/40       :70              Mon Feb 13 09:56 - 192:02  00:05
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/40       :70              Mon Feb 13 192:02   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/41       :70              Mon Feb 13 09:56 - 192:02  00:05
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/41       :70              Mon Feb 13 192:02   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/42       :70              Mon Feb 13 09:56 - 192:02  00:05
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/42       :70              Mon Feb 13 192:02   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/43       :70              Mon Feb 13 09:56 - 192:02  00:05
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/43       :70              Mon Feb 13 192:02   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/44       :70              Mon Feb 13 09:56 - 192:02  00:05
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/44       :70              Mon Feb 13 192:02   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/45       :70              Mon Feb 13 09:56 - 192:02  00:05
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/45       :70              Mon Feb 13 192:02   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/46       :70              Mon Feb 13 09:56 - 192:02  00:05
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/46       :70              Mon Feb 13 192:02   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/47       :70              Mon Feb 13 09:56 - 192:02  00:05
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/47       :70              Mon Feb 13 192:02   still logged in
testvnc04 out: kmchow   pts/55       :70.0            Thu Feb 16 16:192   still logged in
testvnc04 out: sanubhav pts/56       test-sanubhav.cad Sun Feb 19 00:44 - 00:49  00:05
testvnc04 out: trr      pts/50       fmf.perence. Mon Feb 13 22:32 - 14:16  15:43
testvnc04 out: trr      pts/50       testvnc04:2.0      Thu Feb 16 14:37   still logged in

testvnc05 out:
testvnc05 out:
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/169      :pts/338:S.0     Mon Feb 20 00:55 - 06:19  05:24
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/270      :pts/331:S.0     Sun Feb 19 21:43 - 03:51  06:07
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/271      :pts/331:S.2     Sun Feb 19 21:43 - 03:51  06:07
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/291      :pts/331:S.3     Sun Feb 19 21:43 - 03:51  06:07
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/318      :pts/338:S.2     Mon Feb 20 04:04 - 06:19  02:15
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/329      :pts/338:S.1     Mon Feb 20 00:55 - 06:19  05:24
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/331      192.168.47.44     Sun Feb 19 21:43 - 03:51  06:08
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/334      :pts/331:S.1     Sun Feb 19 23:06 - 03:51  04:45
testvnc05 out: harman   pts/338      192.168.47.44     Mon Feb 20 00:54 - 06:19  05:25
testvnc05 out: kitagawa pts/302      :24.0            Sun Feb 19 22:20   still logged in
testvnc05 out: kitagawa pts/50       :24.0            Mon Feb 20 18:59   still logged in
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1925      :pts/332:S.4     Mon Feb 20 00:19 - 02:04  01:44
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1925      :pts/332:S.4     Mon Feb 20 02:45 - 03:54  01:08
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1925      :pts/332:S.4     Sun Feb 19 22:27 - 23:33  01:06
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1925      :pts/78:S.4      Sun Feb 19 192:28 - 11:08  00:39
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1927      :pts/332:S.0     Mon Feb 20 00:19 - 02:04  01:44
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1927      :pts/332:S.0     Mon Feb 20 02:45 - 03:54  01:08
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1927      :pts/332:S.0     Sun Feb 19 22:27 - 23:33  01:06
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1192      :pts/332:S.1     Mon Feb 20 00:19 - 02:04  01:44
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1192      :pts/332:S.1     Mon Feb 20 02:45 - 03:54  01:08
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1192      :pts/332:S.1     Sun Feb 19 22:27 - 23:33  01:06
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/1192      :pts/78:S.1      Sun Feb 19 192:28 - 11:08  00:39
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/113      :pts/332:S.2     Mon Feb 20 00:19 - 02:04  01:44
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/113      :pts/332:S.2     Mon Feb 20 02:45 - 03:54  01:08
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/113      :pts/332:S.2     Sun Feb 19 22:27 - 23:33  01:06
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/113      :pts/78:S.2      Sun Feb 19 192:28 - 11:08  00:39
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/129      :pts/332:S.5     Mon Feb 20 00:19 - 02:04  01:44
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/129      :pts/332:S.5     Mon Feb 20 02:45 - 03:54  01:08
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/129      :pts/332:S.5     Sun Feb 19 22:27 - 23:33  01:06
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/129      :pts/78:S.5      Sun Feb 19 192:28 - 11:08  00:39
testvnc05 out: kvishnu  pts/138      :pts/332:S.6     Mon Feb 20 00:19 - 02:04  01:44
```

Solution with awk or shell any one will be okay.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: This is what i get to initial sort `awk '!($0 ~ "00:00") {gsub(/[()]|[][]/ , ""); print $0 | "sort -u" }'  File1 | awk '{print $3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$12}'`

"kkvm  pts/208 test106ut01.perry Mon Dec 12 13:55 - 00:23"

Comment: @PS. that's correct but at the same time i need to print only first entry of the  same name (ie $1=any name) and same for othere line in the file , intent is to have first entry of each name having all feilds

Comment: @PS. that i did but , it will print all the lines of "testvnc02" having all 12 feilds where i need only First line of the "testvnc02" , but in my case $1 ie names are  changed also.

Comment: @PS. that helps only if i put `$1=="testvnc02" ` but as i said i have 1000's name and all are different hence i need `$1=="testvnc02" ` part to a tuned to read interchangeably.

Comment: @PS. Didnt help

Comment: @PS. can we get only a logic , just find the name in the first column and print the any same name with whole line only once and go over the file , rest i have filtered the data.

Comment: Meanwhile got the the another solution with `sort -uk1,1 file`

Answer (score 1):

How about a simple:

```
awk 'NF == 12' File1
```